# Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle in react native

Tags: react-native

I can't figured out this warning . I examined import and exports but still I can't comprehend what warning means

Require cycle: src\components\index.ts -> src\components\LoadNavigation.tsx -> src\components\index.ts

```
//index.ts
export { default as LoadAssets } from "./LoadAssets";
export { default as Loading } from "./Loading";
export { default as LoadNavigation } from './LoadNavigation';
export { default as SafeAreaView } from "./SafeAreaView";
export { SocialIcon, SocialIconButton, SocialIcons } from "./SocialAuth";


//LoadNavigation.tsx
import { AuthenticationNavigator } from "../navigation/auth-navigation";
import { useTypedSelector } from "../redux";
import { Onboarding } from "../screens";
import { AppRoutes } from "../types/navigation-type";
import Loading from "./Loading";
import { useIsFirstLaunch } from "./../hooks/useIsFirstLaunch";
```

How can I fix this warning. Thanks for any help.